# На каком языке можно реализовать след. задачи

Tags: любой-язык

На каком языке можно реализовать след. задачи
Нужно чтобы программа могла осуществлять "клик" мышки в windows в указаных координатах экрана( допустим в коорд. х.у. находится ярлык на папку My Documents. При запуске программы она могла бы симитировать двойнои клик в коорд. х.у. и открыть папку.) Также нужно распознавать цвет или хотя бы изменение цвета отдельных пикселей экрана в заданных координатах. 
Спасибо

Comment: Ответ может быть только один: Visual Basic

Comment: я такую задачу в свое время писал на Delphi 6.0 , но лишь потому что на тот момент на другом не кодил )

Answer (score 7):

Для ваших задач можно применить скриптовый язык AutoIt ([официальный сайт](http://www.autoitscript.com/), [русскоязычный форум](http://autoit-script.ru/))

AutoIt часто используют для автоматизации каких-либо рутинных действий, [написания ботов для игр](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126957/) и т.д.

Вот пример:

```
$value = 10;

For $i = 1 To $value

    $x = Random(10, @desktopwidth - 10)
    $y = Random(10, @desktopheight - 10)
    $speed = Random(0, 30)

    MouseMove($x, $y, $speed)

    MouseClick("left")

    $color = PixelGetColor($x, $y)
    MsgBox (1, "Цвет пикселя", "Пиксель в точке "&$x&", "&$y&" имеет цвет "&Hex($color, 6), 2)

    Sleep(2000)

Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Практически на любом.

Comment: Konkretnei?

Comment: @Abibok: Vse Tyuring-polnye yazyki ekvivalentny.